# pandas.algos._return_false causes PicklingError with dill.dump_session on CentOS

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pickle, dill

I have a code framework which involves dumping sessions with dill. This used to work just fine, until I started to use pandas. The following code raises a PicklingError on CentOS release 6.5:

```
import pandas
import dill
dill.dump_session('x.dat')
```

The problem seems to stem from pandas.algos. In fact, it's enough to run this to reproduce the error:

```
import pandas.algos
import dill
dill.dump_session('x.dat') / dill.dumps(pandas.algos)
```

The error is `pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <cyfunction lambda1 at 0x1df3050>: it's not found as pandas.algos.lambda1`.

The thing is, this error is not raised on my pc. Both of them have same versions of pandas (0.14.1), dill (0.2.1), and python (2.7.6).

Looking on the badobjects, I get:

```
>>> dill.detect.badobjects(pandas.algos, depth = 1)
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, 
'_return_true': <cyfunction lambda2 at 0x1484d70>, 
'np': <module 'numpy' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/__init__.pyc'>, 
'_return_false': <cyfunction lambda1 at 0x1484cc8>, 
'lib': <module 'pandas.lib' from '/home/talkr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so'>}
```

This seems to be due to different handling of `pandas.algos` by the two OS-s (perhaps different compilers?). On my PC, where `dump_session` is without errors, `pandas.algos._return_false` is `<cyfunction <lambda> at 0x06DD02A0>`, while on CentOS it's `<cyfunction lambda1 at 0x1df3050>`. Why is it handled differently?

Comment: Things you can try to pinpoint what's going on might be to see what pandas puts into the global namespace.  If nothing, then the best I can say is to turn on `dill.detect.trace(True)` and try again.  That should at least show you more of what's happening during failure.  There is also `dill.detect.badobjects` and other tools you can try, to see what's causing the error.  Do you know how to import lambda1?  If so, that might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not seeing what you are seeing on a mac.  Here's what I see, using the same version of `pandas`.  I do see that you are using a different version of `dill`.  I'm using the version from github.  I'll check if there was a tweak to saving modules or globals in `dill` that might have had that impact on some distros.

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 13 2014, 02:29:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
>>> import dill
>>> dill.detect.trace(True)
>>> dill.dump_session('x.pkl')
M1: <module '__main__' (built-in)>
F2: <function _import_module at 0x1069ff140>
D2: <dict object at 0x106a0b280>
M2: <module 'dill' from '/Users/mmckerns/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill-0.2.2.dev-py2.7.egg/dill/__init__.pyc'>
M2: <module 'pandas' from '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.pyc'>
```

Here is what I get for `pandas.algos`,

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 13 2014, 02:29:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas.algos
>>> import dill
>>> dill.dumps(pandas.algos)
'\x80\x02cdill.dill\n_import_module\nq\x00U\x0cpandas.algosq\x01\x85q\x02Rq\x03.'
```

Here's what I get for `pandas.algos._return_false`:

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 13 2014, 02:29:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill
>>> import pandas.algos
>>> dill.dumps(pandas.algos._return_false)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mmckerns/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill-0.2.2.dev-py2.7.egg/dill/dill.py", line 180, in dumps
    dump(obj, file, protocol, byref, file_mode, safeio)
  File "/Users/mmckerns/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill-0.2.2.dev-py2.7.egg/dill/dill.py", line 173, in dump
    pik.dump(obj)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 317, in save
    self.save_global(obj, rv)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 748, in save_global
    (obj, module, name))
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <cyfunction lambda1 at 0x10d403cc8>: it's not found as pandas.algos.lambda1
```

So, I can now reproduce your error.

This looks like an unpicklable object, based on how it's built. *However, it should be able to be pickled inside the module… as it is for me.*  You seem to have pinpointed the difference between what you are seeing in the object pandas builds on CentOS.

Looking at the `pandas` codebase, `pandas.algos` is a `pyx` file… so that's `cython`.
And here's the code.

```
_return_false = lambda self, other: False
```

Were that in a `.py` file, I know it would serialize.  I have no idea how `dill` works for `cython` generated lambdas… (e.g. a lambda `cyfunction`).

It looks like there was a commit (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/commit/73c71dfca10012e25c829930508b5d6f7ccad5ff) in which `_return_false` was moved outside a class into the module scope.  Do you see that on both CentOS and your PC?  It may be that the v0.14.1 for different distros was cut off slightly different git versions… depending on how you installed pandas.

So apparently, I can pick up a `lambda1` by trying to get the source of the object… which for lambda, if it can't get the source, `dill` will grab by name… and apparently it's named `lambda1`… even though that doesn't show up in the .pyx file.  Maybe it's due to how `cython` builds the lambdas.

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 13 2014, 02:29:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas.algos
>>> import dill
>>> dill.source.importable(pandas.algos._return_false)
'from pandas import lambda1\n'
```

The difference might be coming from `cython`… since the code is generated from a `.pyx` in `pandas`.  What's your versions of `cython`?  Mine is 0.20.2.

Comment: But I get the same error on my pc with `dill.dumps(pandas.algos._return_false)`: `PicklingError: Can't pickle <cyfunction <lambda> at 0x06DD02A0>: it's not found as pandas.algos.lambda1`

Comment: The question is… why the heck is CentOS cracking open `pandas`, when it should just allow `dill` to serialize the module by reference, and everything work out?

Comment: I also have no idea why CentOS is building a `lambda1` as opposed to a `<lambda>`.  That might be something to google around a bit for.

Comment: That commit was from 2012, 2014 was only a couple of months ago, so even if two 0.14.1 versions were cut from different commits (i.e. one not from the tag) they'll both definitely still have that. +1 on detective work anyway.

Comment: The problem was indeed with cython. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704505/cython-lambda1-vs-lambda) for further details. The minute I managed to recompile pandas with the new cython, the problem was solved.